# Can an extension remove its custom fields on uninstall?

Tags: custom-fields, extension, developer

As the developer of an extension that creates its own custom fields, what can I do to cause those custom fields to be removed when the extension is uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension needs to include an Upgrader class containing an `uninstall` function. In there you can use the api to delete the custom fields and custom group. Generate the Upgrader class in civix using the command:

```
civix generate:upgrader
```

Read more documentation on this at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/#add-a-database-upgrader-installer-and-uninstaller

Answer (score 2):

@coleman's answer is accurate, but there are less manual ways to approach this. See Tim's post [API and the Art of Installation](https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/api-and-the-art-of-installation), which outlines the use of [`hook_civicrm_managed`](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_managed) as well as a `civix` helper/naming convention *.mgd.php. Here's an [example](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/012b9347b7abf94177a0f8b41b612fd683961a0c/CRM/Volunteer/Form/VolunteerReport.mgd.php) in CiviVolunteer, though it's for a different entity.

If you're adding custom tables, you may wish to avail yourself of another `civix` helper/naming convention. Your extension's `Upgrader` class automatically scans for files named `*_uninstall.sql` in the extension's sql directory when the extension is uninstalled. Here's another CiviVolunteer [example](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/012b9347b7abf94177a0f8b41b612fd683961a0c/sql/volunteer_uninstall.sql).

Comment: That said, I don't think I've tried this the `managed` approach with entities that depend on one another. Maybe naming them so that they run in the right order (e.g., 001_customGroups.mgd.php, 002_customFields.mgd.php) will work, but I haven't tried it.